# Stream Analytics to CosmosDB always fails

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-stream-analytics

The errors I'm getting don't match up with what I'm sending in my query.

My query:

```
SELECT
    udf.CreateGuid('') AS [id],
    udf.CreateGuid('') AS [DocumentId],
    BlobName,
    BlobLastModifiedUtcTime,
    [telmetry].[event_type] as PartitionKey,
    -- webhook
    [telmetry].[id] AS [hook_id],
    [telmetry].[event_version],
    [telmetry].[create_time],
    [telmetry].[resource_type],
    [telmetry].[event_type],
    [telmetry].[summary],
    [telmetry].[resource],
    [telmetry].[links]
INTO
    [cosmosdb2]
FROM
    [telemetrydepot] AS [telmetry]
TIMESTAMP BY [telmetry].[create_time]
```

Here's the export config:

[image]

I've tried setting the DocumentId property to `DocumentId` or `id` with no success. I'm even throwing additional ID, DocumentId and PartitionKey fields into the results just to get something to save with no success (also trying individual runs putting id or DocumentId in the CosmosDB Document Id property. Can't get anything to save...

The errors I'm getting back say:

`An error occurred while preparing data for DocumentDB. The output record does not contain the column DocumentId to use as the partition key property by DocumentDB`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DocumentDB is complaining that you've configured the collection's partition key as `DocumentId` but no such column was in your output. I've found when I alias columns in ASA the column names in the output end up lowercase...

ASA doesn't care about the case but DocumentDB will. Try creating a new collection with partition key set to `documentid`. You can review the current key under "settings" in the portal for docdb.

Note `Document id` in ASA output properties controls what goes in the `id` field. It can be different than the field you partition by in DocumentDB. For example in one of my jobs I want to organize the database by `deviceID` but identify documents based on `messageType`. Because I have to alias `deviceID`, it loses its upper case letters and I have to set the partition key to `deviceid`. Then I set my `Document id` to `messageType`:

[image]

[image]

I get documents that look like this:

{
  "deviceid": "MyDeviceIdentifier",
  /*...*/,
  "id": "MyMessageType"
}